# Akka getting started tutorial and dead letters

Tags: scala, akka

I just tried going though the getting started tutorial located here

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html#getting-started-first-scala

When running the example, everything works, but I get a dead letters message from each of my workers saying it cant send a `akka.dispatch.sysmsg.Terminate` from the worker to the master.

I'm guessing that this is because the master gets shutdown before the workers. How do I rectify this?  If I comment out `context.stop(self)` the issues goes away, but, can I be certain that everything gets closed correctly when `context.system.shutdown()` is called from the listener.

And say I actually wanted to shut down only the master and the workers (not the system), how would I do this without getting the dead letters error I get when using `context.stop(self)` as advised by the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: please do not use such an old version of Akka if at all possible, currently we are at 2.2.3.

The messages you are seeing are not indicative of a problem (and as such they are *not* printed as errors), hence you should not try to fix them.

Comment: thanks for the answer :) I shall just ignore them. (just for the record, I'm using the lastest stable branch, however, the documentation from 2.2.3 didn't have as meaty a getting started example, so I used the one linked :)